# Can I anchor a SwiftUI view in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit

I am trying to place some SwiftUI "widgets" on the walls around my office in RealityKit.

Is this possible?

Something like this:

```
let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .vertical)
view.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    
let swiftUIView = Text("Hello world")
let entity = SwiftUIViewEntity(view: swiftUIView)
    
anchor.addChild(entity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. For that, use [ImageRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/imagerenderer), `ModelEntity` and `Material` objects.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer().ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {        
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {            
        let label = ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 250, height: 500)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        Text("Hello World")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
        }            
        let texture = ImageRenderer(content: label)
        var mat = UnlitMaterial()
        
        if let image = texture.uiImage {                
            let imageName = "helloWorld"
            let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                in: .userDomainMask)[0]
                                     .appendingPathComponent(imageName)
            
            if let jpegData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.95) {
                try? jpegData.write(to: url)
            }
            mat.color.texture = try? .init(.init(.load(contentsOf: url)))
        }
        
        let plane = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: 0.5, height: 1.0)
        let model = ModelEntity(mesh: plane, materials: [mat])

        let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .vertical)
        anchor.addChild(model)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. But I wonder is there really no other way than to convert to an image and save it to disk? So many limitations there - no animations, no data refreshes without completely tearing it down, etc.

Comment: Despite the fact that RealityKit has `VideoMaterial` object, I have not yet seen any native (or third-party) solution where the content of the animated SwiftUI view could be passed as a video stream to the RealityKit material. Nonetheless, we can record video from the screen using the `ReplayKit` framework.

Answer (score 0):

Given the date of this question, this answer may not be able to help you right now, as it’s only for visionOS, but `RealityView` lets you specify *attachments*, which are SwiftUI views, that you can then get entities for that you can put anywhere in your scene.

Here’s a snippet of code from inside one of my visionOS app’s views:

```swift
RealityView
{ ioContent, inAttachments in
    if let scene = try? await Entity(named: "Immersive", in: realityKitContentBundle)
    {
        ioContent.add(scene)
        scene.addChild(self.appState.fingerEntities[.left]!)
        scene.addChild(self.appState.fingerEntities[.right]!)
        
        if let attachment = inAttachments.entity(for: "earthLabel")
        {
            attachment.position = [0, 0.02, 0]
            self.appState.fingerEntities[.right]!.addChild(attachment)
        }
    }
}
attachments:
{
    Attachment(id: "earthLabel")
    {
        Text("\(self.appState.rightFingertipPos.x, specifier: "% .3f"), \(self.appState.rightFingertipPos.y, specifier: "% .3f"), \(self.appState.rightFingertipPos.z, specifier: "% .3f")")
    }
}
```

Hopefully Apple brings these new APIs to iOS as well, and hopefully this answer helps those searching for how to do this in visionOS.